# Deployment in WebLogic Issue

Tags: weblogic

I am a newbie.I am using Weblogic 10.0.0.0..I am getting an validation error in first page(Login Page wit user name and pwd) as "logger is not initialized",while deploying.  I do the same thing with tomcat, and the .war is imported and deployed is success. What is the reason? and also ,in weblogic 10.0.0.0 we have two jdk's(jdk 1.6 and Jrockit)...in my system i m having 1.6.0_17..so which one it takes.i forgot which i choose while installing..whether it takes from wblogic jdk or which one?..wher i m going wrong..its a small one i notice..but could not figure out..plz lemme kno??

Answer (score 0):

This is either because you haven't configured your WLS installation correctly. When you first setup your console there is a parameter you have to change in your auth file that if not set with cause this issue.

Or you are selecting logging during deployment from the admin console and you haven't configured log4j in your application.